# What is a "ios open sdk toolchain"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, toolchain

I am starting developing tools for my jailbroken iPhone (using THEOS). I read some really interesting articles about using "hidden functionality" and the authors always use the terms "open sdk" or "open sdk toolchain". What exactly does open sdk mean? If I could guess, I would say an open sdk is an sdk with all header-files (even the normally hidden ones). Is that correct?

I found the tool class-dump (https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) wich helps to extract all header files from ios SDKs. Do I get a "open SDK" when I extract all Header-files from a normal IOS SDK ... even if I use it whit a 5.0 or 6.0 SDK? Because I found some articles like http://www.alexwhittemore.com/using-the-open-tool-chain-in-xcode-for-both-os-2-2-and-3-0/ they always are about the 3.0 SDK, wich is a pretty old one.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know what an SDK is, Software development Kit. :)
iOS Open Dev SDK is an SDK which allows you to use some MORE templates in Xcode such as:

Action Menu Plugin, Activator Listener, CaptainHook Tweak, Cocoa Touch Library,  Command Line tool, Logos Tweak,Notification Center Widget, SBSettings Toggle.
ioS Open Dev Templates provide many options to program code for iOS.

You can download it by googling for it.

ClassDump is a tool which allows you to dump the headers out of an objective c - executable. This gives you the option to look at the methods of the .h(eader) files and use them to build your tweak or whatever.

Comment: so the difference between the "normal SDK" and a "open sdk" is, that the open sdk provides more templates???

Comment: You could say that, yes. the SDK contains stuff so you can program(frameworks and all) ios open dev does that too, just custom things so you can progra more stuff and have more templates